# bootstrap Wordpress style sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

I am creating a sidebar for an application, I would like it to have the same functionality as the WordPress dashboard menu, for example:
Fixed left - shows full sidebar on desktop view (Icons and label).
Tablet view, only icons display.
Mobile view no sidebar, burger menu displays top left, once clicked the full sidebar shows down the left side of the screen.

I have been searching for examples so I do not have to 'reinvent the wheel' however only example I have found contain a portion of the functionality I require.  So I thought I would ask if anyone knows of an example that may help further.  If not I will re-create re-using the examples I have found.

Thanks,

Comment: The admin template AdminLTE uses such functionality, maybe this can help you further? https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html

Comment: Try Having ago yourself... Its gonna use Jquery and CSS... When you post some code we can help you out :)

Comment: Thanks guys will do